# Exercise problem 21, Chapter 4 from Blitzstein and Hwang, Intro to Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, expected-value, self-learning

I am self-learning basic undergrad calculus-based probability. I would like someone to verify if my solution is correct, and I didn't make any unreasonable assumptions. I am posting my attempt/solution below:

> Let $X \sim Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})$ and $Y \sim (n+1,\frac{1}{2})$ independently.
>
> (a) Let $V = \min(X,Y)$ be the smaller of $X,Y$ and let $W=\max(X,Y)$ be the larger of $X,Y$. So, if $X$ crystallizes to $x$ and $Y$ crystallizes to $y$, then $V$ crystallizes to $\min(x,y)$ and $W$ crystallizes to $\max(x,y)$. Find $E(V) + E(W)$.

**Solution.** (My Attempt)

The PMF of the random variables $V,W$ can be deduced, but it can be computationally very laborious.

Observe that, the sum of the rvs, $V + W = X + Y$, the total number of successes in both the experiments.

So,

\begin{align*}
E(V) + E(W) &= E(V + W)\\
&= E(X + Y) \\
&= E(X) + E(Y)\\
&= \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n+1}{2}\\
&= \frac{2n+1}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: I might write the final answer as $n+\frac12$, not that it makes much difference

Comment: Haven't heard "crystallize" used to describe a realized value of an RV--gonna have to use that one from now on!